# SharePoint 2016 On-Premise Configuring Database after Migration

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sql-server, windows-server

I have SP2016 installed on my Windows Server with a Database on a separate server. I moved to new servers and after that the SP failed to start.

So, I am having a new server holding SP apps on IIS, and another one holding SP databases and I want to connect between them.

I tried to use cliconfig.exe and created an Alias but also that did not work. Whenever I run the SP it keeps loading until timeout.

I think that using Alias will not work as the new server carries the same name of the old server.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you changed the names of the servers? If you have, the configuration will be wrong since SharePoint will still have references to the old server names.

Comment: How to do that? I believe that both old and new servers carry the same name. I am sorry but totally new to SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the SharePoint database from one server to another can be achieved with the following steps:

1. Stop All SharePoint Services:
2. Backup & Restore All SharePoint Databases to the new SQL Server
3. Change the SQL Alias to Point to the new SQL Server
4. Start All SharePoint Services

> Check the details at [Move all databases in SharePoint Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/move-all-databases) and [Restore SharePoint database 2019](https://debug.to/5926/restore-sharepoint-database-2019)

Comment: Actually that did not work and I want to run again the config wizard. However, it seems to be very slow in a weird way, it takes hours to start and not responding.